# Radio Buttons Fill

Tags: html, css, radio-button

I'm Having trouble with my radio buttons, I don't want them to entirely fill the circle. Any word of advice. Here is link to what is happening on Codepen.

https://codepen.io/winterlion/pen/LYYJwZP

```css
.item .text {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.item .text:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: text-bottom;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid #235b96;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0px gray inset;
}

.item input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

.item input[type="radio"]:checked+label .text:before {
  content: '';
  color: #235b96;
  background-color: #479623;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <input type="radio" id="r1" name="group1" value="trial1" />
  <label for="r1" class="wrapper">
    <span class="background"></span>
    <h1 class="rp-text">Radio Buttons</h1>
    <hr class="split-hr">
    <br>
    <span class="text"></span>
  </label>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <input type="radio" id="r2" name="group1" value="trial2" />
  <label for="r2" class="wrapper">
    <span class="background"></span>
    <h1 class="rp-text">Buttons</h1>
    <span class="text"></span>
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question right, you just want to move styles related to a green dot to an ::after pseudo element that must be a bit smaller than ::before.

```css
.item .text {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.item .text::before,
.item .text::after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.item .text::before {
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  border: 2px solid  #235b96;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0px gray inset;
}

.item input[type="radio"]:checked + label .text::after {
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
  top: 5px;
}

.item input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

.item input[type="radio"]:checked + label .text:after {
  color:  #235b96;
  background-color: #479623;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <input type="radio" id="r1" name="group1" value="trial1" />
  <label for="r1" class="wrapper">
    <span class="background"></span>
    <h1 class="rp-text">Radio Buttons</h1>
    <hr class="split-hr">
    <br>
    <span class="text"></span>
  </label>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <input type="radio" id="r2" name="group1" value="trial2" />
  <label for="r2" class="wrapper">
    <span class="background"></span>
    <h1 class="rp-text">Buttons</h1>
    <span class="text"></span>
  </label>
</div>
```